# Power BI: Calculated column or Measure

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns, measure

I have following data:

**Table**: PriceTable

```
Price  Applicable1  Applicable2  Percentage
--------------------------------------------
100    Yes          Yes          0.10
200    Yes          No           0.50
300    No           Yes          0.30
500    Yes          Yes          0.40
```

I want to calculate the Percentage of price in last column and show in the table/matrix in the power bi report.

**Scenario**: If both column `Applicable1 and Applicable2` are equal to `Yes` then calculate the percentage of price in the final column.

**My try**: I have taken `New Column` and added following **DAX**:

```
Commission = IF( PriceTable[Applicable1] = "Yes" &&
                 PriceTable[Applicable2] = "Yes", 
                 PriceTable[Price] * PriceTable[Percentage], 0)
```

**Question**:

> 1. Which one should I use `New Column` OR `Measure`?
> 2. If `Measure`, then how to calculate the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob Collie has an excellent blog post on "[When to Use Measures vs. Calc Columns](https://powerpivotpro.com/2013/02/when-to-use-measures-vs-calc-columns/)"

And Reza Rad has another good post:

[Measure vs Calculated Column: The Mysterious Question? Not!](http://radacad.com/measure-vs-calculated-column-the-mysterious-question-not)

My favourite take-away from this is:

> If you want to put it on rows, columns, slicers, or report filters, it
>   MUST be a column

Answer (score 3):

Use new Column as you calculation is not dynamic it's row wise calculation so use NewColumn.
Even it's fast as It's precalculated If you use dynamic it calculates the value every time when you launch the report which slow down your report loading